# git commit miss, can't get it

Tags: python, git, git-commit, gitpython

I clone the 'Apache/tomcat' git repo to use some info about commit.

However, when i use `git.repo('repo local address').iter_commits()`, i can't get some commits.
Besides, I can't search these in github search engine.

For example, [commit 69c56080fb3355507e1b55d014ec0ee6767a6150](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/69c56080fb3355507e1b55d014ec0ee6767a6150) is in the 'Apache tomcat' repo, however, [search '69c56080fb3355507e1b55d014ec0ee6767a6150' in 'in this repository'](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/search?q=69c56080fb3355507e1b55d014ec0ee6767a6150)  get nothing.
It's amazing for me.

It seems like that the commit isn't in the master branch, so can't be searched?

I want to know the theory behind this and how to get info about these 'missing' commits in Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`repo.iter_commits()`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=iter_commits#git.repo.base.Repo.iter_commits), with no arguments, gives you the commits which can be reached by tracing back through the parent(s) of the current commit. In other words, if you are in the `master` branch, it will only give you commits that are part of the `master` branch.

You can give it a `rev` argument which, [among other things](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions), can be a branch name. For example, `iter_commits(rev='8.5.x')` ought to give you all commits in the `8.5.x` branch, which will include `69c5608`. You can use another function, [`repo.branches()`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=iter_branches#git.repo.base.Repo.branches), if you need to get a list of branches.

Alternatively, if you already know the hash of a single commit that you want to look up, you can use [`repo.commit()`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=repo.commit#git.repo.base.Repo.commit), again with a `rev` parameter which in this case is the full or abbreviated commit hash: `commit(rev='69c5608')`.

Comment: Thanks. It's clearly explaine. I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that this commit is in the branch `8.5.x` and not `master`. You can see this in the first link. It will show which branches include it. The GitHub search algorithm only searches the `master`/`main`/`trunk` branch.

To find it via `git` python library, try changing to that branch. See these instructions on how to switch branches: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#switching-branches

Comment: Thanks, I will try later.